# Autosizing rows and columns in TableView?

Tags: tableview

In v12.1 TableView is finally documented! It's more stable than it's ever been but my one qualm with it is that I need it to *auto-size the columns and row*s so that ***all items are fully visible with their cells***.

For example, when the TableView's takes a matrix of Expressions, it doesn't look good (too much cut-off):

```
data = Values /@ Normal @ ResourceFunction["RecentResourceFunctions"][];
TableView[data, Expression, ImageSize->Full, ItemSize->10]
```

[image]

To simplify the problem, assume that TableView knows the dimensions of the table and adapts the column widths and row heights. Here's some code to play with it:

```
dim={5, 5}; maxStringLength=10;
Slider[Dynamic[maxStringLength], {1,30,1}]
Dynamic[table=Map[ResourceFunction["RandomString"], RandomInteger[{1, maxStringLength}, dim], {2}];]
TableView[Dynamic@table, ItemSize -> {{{Scaled[0.1]}}}, AllowedDimensions -> Automatic, ImageSize->{Full, 500}]
```

[image]

Comment: `TableView` is all about the speed of presenting millions of items and editing them.  I doubt you will see `Grid`'s automatic sizing behaviors integrated, since that is part of what makes `Grid` slow.

Comment: I understand, but I'd say it's not really presenting items well if they are all cut off!

Comment: Items are cut off in spreadsheets all the time.  It is just comes with the territory.  I'd be happier if the `Alignment` was different...  Probably.

Comment: @M.R. Could you deal with all columns being the same width to display everything?

Comment: No, each column should be the width of widest element in that column

Comment: @M.R. okay, I can get that, I'll post something shortly. The new line character and `"\n"` don't parse right with `TableView`, so finding the proper way to do row heights is going to be strange, especially for non-character inputs.

Comment: I tried using rasterize on the expression but it was slow and the sizes weren’t comparable for things like text and summary boxes

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do something inspired by this? I basically just brute-forced it, though, so...

```
data =
{{"Paris\nSecond Line", "France", 2200000},
{"New York", "US", 8500000},
{"Beijing", "China", 21700000}};

TableView[#,
Boxes,
ItemSize ->
{{Max /@ StringLength /@ Flatten /@ #} - 1,
{Max /@ Map[Length /@ ## &]@#}} &@
(StringSplit[#, "\n"] & /@
Map[ToString /@ ## &]@Transpose@#) &@#, 
AllowedDimensions -> Dimensions@#] &@data
```

Trying to use `Dynamic` with this leads to a bunch of errors, so it's not a solution, but if your data is predefined and you don't need to be filling the dataset prior to using `Setting` or the related function, maybe this is something in the right direction? Also, as mentioned in the comments, the `"\n"` doesn't parse to a new line until you type in the field of the Table, then it properly goes to a new line.

Comment: Add some boxes to your data, like Now, TimeSeries, Image, or Url, and see if it holds up

Comment: @M.R. I'll do that! Also, the new line parses with `Boxes` as a type.

Comment: Oh and long strings that wrap around!

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that I'll have to fiddle with it a bit more, I had only considered Strings!

Comment: Any luck with the additional types?@CATrevillian

Comment: @M.R. I'll poke a bit more back at it, the issue is in determining the actual width of the `Boxes` `DisplayForm`, I think. That's something I'm not too familiar with, how to delve deeply enough to get that information. If one assumes that the `DateObject` will always contain the same amount of information, that is one possible route, but even then there does not seem to be any correlation (that I had yet solidified) between how large it displays and, say, the width that a rasterized form might take.